# How do i open a .dump file format in ubuntu without using Wireshark?

Tags: dump

I have DoS attack downloaded datasets in a dump format i.e llDoS.dump .

It opens using wireshark in ubuntu but i need to modify and apply Support vector machine classifier.

Can anyone tell me how do i open a .dump file for reading and writing other than using wireshark.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the libpcap library (which is used by wireshark and tcpdump) if you don't mind writing your own code to parse the files.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Using wireshark and convert to PDML. PDML is an XML.

    There should be option to export back to [PCAP][1]


  [1]: http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/18998/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-pcap-file-to-remove-addresses
```

Comment: I have to use that .dump file using weka. How can i use it Sir?

Comment: Wirshark > Load .dump file > Export Packet Dissections > as PDML

Comment: Thank you sir, But can it used in Weka software later on?

Comment: Try that. I dnt know about weka.